# Script for adding new KeyboardShortcuts on MacOs (Leopard)

Tags: shell, scripting, keyboard-shortcuts, osx-leopard

Is it possible to add KeyboardShortcuts in MacOs (Leopard) using shell or other programmatic way? Basically, something to automate the steps of opening Keyboard&Mouse in SystemPreferences, selecting the last tab "KeyboardShortcuts", Clicking "+" to add a new one and filling the info.
   Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following AppleScript should do the trick, with 3 variables:

1. `app_name`: name of an application that you want to assign the shortcut to, e.g. Safari
2. `menu_title`: exact menu name to execute
3. `keystrokes`: the actual shortcut

---

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    activate
    set current pane to pane "com.apple.preference.keyboard"
end tell

tell application "System Events"
    tell process "System Preferences"
        tell window "Keyboard"
            click button 3 of tab group 1
            tell sheet 1
                click pop up button 1
                click last menu item of menu 1 of pop up button 1
                keystroke "/Applications/" & app_name & ".app"
                keystroke return
                keystroke return
                delay 1

                keystroke menu_title
                keystroke tab

                keystroke last item of keystokes using rest of reverse of keystokes
                delay 1

                click button "Add"
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

The code is referencing the following site:
http://www.rngtng.com/2010/10/29/applescript-to-create-keyboard-shortcuts/